# My input program which stores the given inputs in a text file isnt working properly

Tags: c, string, file, input, io

The text file only takes the last word which was inputted.
Everything works fine except the file writing part where it only stores the last word of the string.
Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    int limit;
    int i;
    printf("How many approxmiate size of you list will be: \n");
    scanf("%d", &limit);
    char list[100][100];
     for(int i=0; i<limit; i++){
        printf("Enter task: \n");
        scanf("%s", &list[i]);
    }
    FILE *store;
    store = fopen("data.txt", "w");
    fprintf(store, "%s",list);
    fclose(store);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't just pass the whole array to `fprintf`. You need to loop over the list and print each string seperately.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your compiler should warn about wrong parameter type for `fprintf`. If not, turn up warning level. For GCC you can do this using options `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: @kaylum How will i exactly loop over the list, do i make another for loop?

Comment: You've already done it once in the `for` loop. Just do it again but this time call `fprintf`. Or just move the `fprintf` into the existing `for` loop.

Comment: After the fopen I suggest you to verify the result stored in `store`, it could be NULL if an error occurs opening the file. In your case the file is created when it opened, but to create it could generate errors (I.E.: `permission denied`, `bad file name`) and then you would have a `segmentation fault` when writing on the file.

Comment: or do it the existing loop, i.e. `fprintf(store, "%s",list[i]);` just after `scanf`

Comment: `scanf("%s", &list[i]);` -> `scanf("%99s", list[i]);`